# IOS: JSON parsing with lazy load images

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, image, lazy-loading

So I've made an android application which parses `JSON` and uses the lazy load technique to load the images. (I'm creating it for a video website and need to show the thumbnail for the video ned to the title). Now I'm making it for `iOS`. I have made it so it shows the title and subtitle and a show a "watch" button with my custom table view cell. Is there any tutorials or articles I could look at to show me how to load the images into an image view?

**Note:** I have searched the web for this but could not find a good article or tutorial for it.

Many Thanks - Charlton Santana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great solution for you is **SDWebImage**

check the below link, it is easy to use.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking has JSON parsing

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking#download-and-parse-json

and image loading

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking#download-and-display-images